# Running docker container with user

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created this docker file to run a python script in docker container.
I am creating a user here and I want this user to run the container from docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER "Vijendra Kulhade" <xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com>
RUN yum makecache fast
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install gcc
RUN yum -y install zlib-devel
RUN yum -y install openssl-devel
RUN yum -y install python-setuptools python-setuptools-devel
RUN yum -y install libyaml
RUN useradd newuser -d /home/newuser
RUN chown -R newuser.newuser /usr/bin/
RUN chown -R newuser.newuser /usr/lib64/
RUN chown -R newuser.newuser /usr/lib/
ENV https_proxy=http://proxy.xxxx.com:8080
RUN easy_install pip
RUN pip -V
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools
```

I use this command to create the image
`docker build -t python-container .`
And I am using 
`docker run --security-opt label=user:newuser -i -t python-container:latest /bin/bash` to run container from image. I was expecting that this would start the container and login into it with `newuser@xxxxxxxx`. But It is not happening.
Please let know how I can achieve that.

Comment: Can you run `docker logs` to see what happen?

Comment: Ubuntu does not have command `yum`, it uses `apt` for package managing. How did you build that image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two possibilities to run docker containers with a user different from root.

---

First possibility: Create user in Dockerfile

In your example Dockerfile, you create user `newuser` with command `useradd`. You can write instruction

```
USER newuser
```

in the Dockerfile. All following commands will be executed as user `newuser`. This goes for all following `RUN` instructions as well as for `docker run` commands.

---

Second possibility: option `--user` (tops possible `USER` instruction in image)

You can use `docker run` option `--user`. It can be used to specify either an UID without a name:

```
docker run --user 1000
```

Or specify UID and GID without a name:

```
docker run --user 1000:100
```

or specify a name only without knowing which UID the user will get:

```
docker run --user newuser
```

---

You can combine both ways. Create a user in Dockerfile with specified (!) UID and GID and add him to all desired groups. Use matching `docker run --user UID:GID`, and your container user will have all attributes you gave him in the Dockerfile.

---

(I do not understand your approach with `--security-opt label=user:newuser`, either it is wrong or it is something I know nothing about.)

Comment: I was just going through the documentation and found `--security-opt label=user:newuser` probably I didn't understand it well. but `docker run --user newuser -i -t image:version /bin/bash` worked for me.